# Server side Remote validation not firing

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-web-api

I am attempting to validate **AccessoryType** for uniqueness.I have put remote validation in model.

Here's code setup,

**In model,**

```
public class AccessoryTypeMasterMetaData
{
    [Remote("checkAccessoryTypeExist", "AccessoryType")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter accessory type.")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Please enter maximum of {1} characters in accessory type.")]

    public string AccessoryType { get; set; }
}
```

**And I have put **checkAccessoryTypeExist** method in API Controller,**

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/AccessoryType/checkAccessoryTypeExist")]
    public IHttpActionResult checkAccessoryTypeExist(string accessoryType, int accessoryTypeID)
    {
        AccessoryTypeMasterService accessoryTypeMasterService = new AccessoryTypeMasterService();

        BaseResponseModel<bool> baseResponseModel = new BaseResponseModel<bool>();
        baseResponseModel.status = true;
        baseResponseModel.data = false;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessoryType))
        {
            baseResponseModel.data = accessoryTypeMasterService.CheckAccessoryType(accessoryType, accessoryTypeID);
            baseResponseModel.message = LES_Common.STATUS_SUCCESS;
        }

        return new BaseResponseResult<bool>(baseResponseModel, Request);

    }
```

So Issue is that Remote validation is not firing at server side
But other all validations are firing(like Required,StringLength )

Is there any problem with my code? Help Me..

Answer (score 0):

In your method declaration there are two parameters  `accessoryType , accessoryTypeID` . And in your `AccessoryTypeMasterMetaData` model you are only apply it on `AccessoryType` . So you will get only AccessoryType value if you require additionally `accessoryTypeID` to check then you need to change `RemoteAttribute` on property something like this :

```
[Remote("checkAccessoryTypeExist", "AccessoryType",HttpMethod = "POST", AdditionalFields = nameof(AccessoryTypeID ), ErrorMessage = "Error message to display." )]
```

And it's better if you change your method signature to :

```
public IHttpActionResult checkAccessoryTypeExist(AccessoryTypeMasterMetaData modelData)
    {


 // You can access it here i.e. modelData.AccessoryType and modelData.AccessoryTypeID

    }
```

Comment: I think you are using lower version that why it not supported. You can remove `nameof(AccessoryTypeID)` and use - `"AccessoryTypeId"` .

Comment: how to use 'GetUrl' field in model side to make it work because my route is    "api/accessoryType/checkAccessoryTypeExist"?

Comment: @MansiKalola , I don't understand why you require `GetUrl` on model side ?? Becasue if you decorate your model property with `Remote` attribute properly then it will automatically calls the defined action from controller. Does above code not working properly ??

Comment: I think code is not recognized "checkAccessoryTypeExist" method so i want to use 'routeName' or 'getURL' ...

Comment: No Mansi, You don't need to bind it manually. You can check it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(vs.98).aspx). Are getting any error or what ?